# Number of words in $\{pi,po\}^*$ of length at most 9

Tags: combinatorics, word-combinatorics

I have a language $L^*$ for $L = \{pi,po\}$ (I think pi counts as one letter and po also as one letter otherwise a max length of 9 is not possible).

The question is how many words I can make with $L^*$ where the maximum length is 9.

The answer is 31, but I do not know how it got calculated. How is this calculated?

Comment: Both $pi$ and $po$ count as two letters for the answer to be correct. Can you count how many strings of length $n$ you can form?

Comment: @quicksort so $pipo$ would be 4 letters then right?

Comment: @quicksort and after thinking i would have no idea how to count that...

Comment: How many strings of length $n$ made of zeroes and ones are there?

Comment: is it 2^n ? sorry if I'm totally wrong, but I just miss something where i proberly would facepalm myself if I found it out.

Comment: Yes, it's $2^n$. Now, if your building blocks are long two characters rather than just one, a string of $n$ characters contains $n/2$ such blocks. How many strings of length exactly $n$ are there? How can you use that to solve your original problem?

Comment: So I have 4,5 building blocks in my case right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are all words in $L^*$ of length at most 9:
$$
\epsilon, \\
pi, po, \\
pipi, pipo, popi, popo, \\
pipipi, pipipo, pipopi, pipopo, popipi, popipo, popopi, popopo, \\
pipipipi, pipipipo, pipipopi, pipipopo, pipopipi, pipopipo, pipopopi, pipopopo, popipipi, popipipo, popipopi, popipopo, popopipi, popopipo, popopopi, popopopo.
$$
In total, there are 31 words.

More generally, suppose that we have $m$ distinct words of length $\ell$. Then the total number of words of length at most $n$ is
$$
\sum_{r=0}^{\lfloor n/\ell \rfloor} m^r =
\frac{m^{\lfloor n/\ell \rfloor+1}-1}{m-1}.
$$
In our case, we get $\frac{2^{\lfloor 9/2 \rfloor + 1}-1}{2-1} = 2^{4+1}-1 = 31$.